# regex match except end of string

Tags: regex

For example, if I have 3 words:

```
throw
growing
plows
```

I'm wanting something that will return only words without 'ow' on the end:

```
growing
plows
```

Basically the exact opposite of:

```
/ow$/
```

So it will only return the words when 'ow' does NOT show up on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*(?<!ow)$
```

You can use `lookbehind` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/4

Comment: That does seem to be working, but I think I may have phrased it wrong. I'm trying to use it with php's preg_replace, so it would only pull out the specific ou, rather than the entire word.
IE:
`$pattern = '/^.*(?<!ow)$/';
$replacement = 'ou';
$replacedString = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, 'growing',1);
`

Comment: @Robbie what exaclty do you want to achieve?replace words not ending in `ow` by `ou`?

Comment: Not replace the entire words, just the 'ow' with an 'ou', but only when it doesn't end in 'ow'.
I found a workaround with preg_match, but I'd really like to at least learn a way to do it view replace, just for my own knowledge.

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*ow$).+
```

Answer (score 0):

Python code:

```
lst = ["throw","growing","plows"]

for item in lst:
    if not str.endswith(item.lower(), "ow"):
        print item
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, when 'ow' does NOT show up at [the end of the word](https://regex101.com/r/gK6qZ8/1):

```
/\b\w+(?<!ow)\b/i
```

Use word boundaries `\b` and word characters `\w` together with lookbehind `(?<!ow)`